# Influence of multiple players in Blackjack

Tags: probability, reference-request, gambling

The usual Blackjack strategy computations involve computing odds for a single player against the house, and the strategy derived this way is well known. It seems the results should be different if you know some  additional cards on the table if you are one of multiple players on the same table. I'm looking for literature references on the value of house edge in those cases, presumably depending on the number of players, position on the table, number of decks and continuous/bulk shuffles.

Comment: Is there any difference between seeing other players' cards and seeing the previous hands of the player and the bank?

Comment: Given the range of possibilities, people generally simulate these computations rather than trying to do them analytically.